# Unable to print output on powershell window which will be used for further read-host input

Tags: powershell

AM trying to get an array output (which has names and indexing) on PS screen so that user can choose from the options he has for input to next steps (Read-host)
Am adding indexing (index numbering) to an array so I can output index number and Name which can be used by used to input for next steps.
But the output on screen is not recorded and is stored somewhere on background and is given along with my "return" statement for that function at the very end of script

Need help form you folks to see why the output is not written on powershell screen (both ISE and powershell 5.1)

```
function CLoneBranch
{
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=0)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]$url,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=1)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[String]$GitConnectionUserName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Position=2)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[securestring]$GitConnectionUserPassword
)
try
{
    $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($GitConnectionUserPassword)
    $plainpwd = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
    # Retrieve list of all repositories
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $GitConnectionUserName,$plainpwd)))
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
        "Accept" = "application/json"}

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
    $gitcred = ("{0}:{1}" -f  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($GitConnectionUserName),$plainpwd)

    $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $headers -Uri ("{0}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=1.0" -f $url)
    $json = convertFrom-JSON $resp.Content
    If($resp)
    {
        [Array]$RepoArray = Add-IndexNumberToArray ($json.value)

        [int]$Selectedrepo = 0
        # use the current repo if there is only one repo available
        if ($RepoArray.Count -eq 1) 
        {
            $Selectedrepo = 1
        }
        while($Selectedrepo -gt $RepoArray.Count -or $Selectedrepo -lt 1)
        {

            Write-host "Please select a Repo from the list"
            $RepoArray | Select-Object IndexNumber , Name | Format-Table -verbose
**###### This is not written on the screen for user to look for what he has to input but some how at the end of function it returns the output using retun statement which I don't want ##########**

            try
            {
                $Selectedrepo = Read-Host "Please enter a selection from 1 to $($RepoArray.count)"
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Warning -Message 'Invalid option, please try again.'
            }
        }
        if($($RepoArray[$Selectedrepo - 1].Name))
        {
            $RepoName = $($RepoArray[$Selectedrepo - 1].Name)
        }
        #write-verbose "You Selected Repo to download : $RepoName"
    }
}
       catch
 {
     Write-Error " Exception while cloning the repo or a specific branch"
     Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
     Write-Error " ErrorStack: $Error[0]"
     exit 1;
 }
 Return $RepoName
 }


function Add-IndexNumberToArray (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[array]$array
)
{
for($i=0; $i -lt $array.Count; $i++) 
{ 
    Add-Member -InputObject $array[$i] -Name "IndexNumber" -Value ($i+1) -MemberType NoteProperty 
}
$array
```

}

Comment: You must move the function definition _before_ invoking it …

Comment: FYI... You can assign Read-Host responses to a variable and output to the screen at the same time using Variable Squeezing --- https://ridicurious.com/2019/03/07/powershell-variable-squeezing ---, then use that variable wherever. Depending on your PowerShell version, as a rule, don't use Write-Host if you plan to use the data elsewhere. AS per the author of PowerShell --- http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful --- Later versions Write-Host, see this from the author 
 ---https://twitter.com/jsnover/status/727902887183966208

Comment: thanku will check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distilling your code down to a minimal repro, we get this:

```bsh
function Invoke-MyFunction
{
   write-host "here 1"
   @("aaa", "bbb") | format-table -Verbose
   write-host "here 2"
   return "ccc"
}

$x = Invoke-MyFunction
"---"
$x
```

which outputs:

```
here 1
here 2
---
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

The reason you don't see the output from `@("aaa", "bbb") | format-table -Verbose` between `here 1` and `here 2` on the console is that it's being returned from the function as part of the output pipeline and assigned to `$x`, and *not* written to the console inside the `Invoke-MyFunction` function.

Like most programming languages, PowerShell's `return` will return a value and exit the function, *but* you can also stream values into the "output pipeline" by simply not capturing expressions into a variable. For example:

```bsh
function Invoke-MultipleOutputs
{
    1
    "aaa"
    return "ccc"
}
$x = Invoke-MultipleOutputs
$x
```

`$x` will contain an array of values - in this case `@( 1, "aaa", "ccc" )`.

This is equivalent to

```bsh
function Invoke-MultipleOutputs
{
    Write-Output 1
    Write-Output "aaa"
    return "ccc"
}
$x = Invoke-MultipleOutputs
$x
```

In your code, your're doing this: `$RepoArray | Select-Object IndexNumber , Name | Format-Table -verbose` which is converting `$RepoArray` into a set of formatted table objects, but then because the result is an unassigned expression it's being written to the output pipeline rather than being displayed on the console.

To fix this, you need to render the output of `Format-Table` as a string and then write it to the console which you can do with `out-host`...

```bsh
$RepoArray | Select-Object IndexNumber , Name | Format-Table -verbose | out-host
```

or `out-string`...

```bsh
$text = $RepoArray | Select-Object IndexNumber , Name | Format-Table -verbose | out-string
write-host $text
```

Going right back to my first example, we get:

```bsh
function Invoke-MyFunction
{
   write-host "here 1"
   @("aaa", "bbb") | format-table -Verbose | out-host
   write-host "here 2"
   return "ccc"
}

$x = Invoke-MyFunction
"---"
$x
```

which now outputs:

```
here 1
aaa
bbb
here 2
---
ccc
```

If you update your `$RepoArray | ...` line in the same way you should see it being displayed on the console where you expect it to be.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Very nice explanation and an answer.. really appreciate the nice explanation you gave.. This worked like a champ